# Creating a Wizard Interface with MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Does anyone have any pointers on how to go about creating a "wizard interface" using Access 2010?  I need a sequential set of forms that will be capable of branching the flow based on answers from the user and data found in the database.  I have used Access before for some CRUD/Reports type of applications, but in this case I can't seem to wrap my head around how to get started on such a complex machine.

Before anyone suggests it, I cannot use anything but Access due to client requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel your pain ... working with Access gets so difficult where there are complex requirements.

1. **Gather and document the requirements**

   Make sure you've teased out every possible wrinkle and contingency from the client, and put it into a flow chart or something.
2. **Extract the models**

   Figure out what models are being used -- customers, addresses, vendors, products, etc.  These will have to be created as tables or adapted to existing ones.
3. **Extract other variables**

   What could potentially change over time and/or what will the client want to be able to change via an admin screen?  You'll have to decide which of these variables to put into tables, and which are ok in the code (form logic and/or VBA).
4. **Design the tables for the wizard views**

   I imagine you'll want a *wizard screens* table, where each row corresponds to a step; each should have (other than an *id* column) a *previous screen* column, and a *form name* or *form template name* column.  You'll need a second table *choices* with a many-to-one foreign key linking back to *screens*; each row here will correspond to a possible outcome of the view, and the target next step in the wizard.
5. **Design the forms**

   Finally, design the forms corresponding to each wizard step or template, pulling data from  the structures in 1-4 as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer, I am going ahead and marking it.  Great idea on the screens->choices tables!  So I am thinking I need a class that understands how to direct the flow based on these tables.  Now I just need a way to standardize how the forms will return which outcome they had so that it can do that.  I am sure I can come up with something, but if you had any thoughts on the matter I'd love to hear them.  Either way, thanks again for a quick and thorough answer.

Comment: @JoelClark, regarding the 'forms' part of the wizard - one technique i have used to keep the variables local throughout the wizard is to make the different 'pages' as different pages on a `TabControl` and setting the `Style` property to None. This may simplify some of the complex programming tasks of passing values between forms. Let me know if you want additional information on this approach.